# iPhone: How to get top left corner coordinate of a UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I just want to get the x,y coordinate of the top left corner of a view, how might I do this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
CGPoint topLeft = theView.frame.origin;
```

Comment: any idea how to get corner coordinates of  visibleMapRect ?

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan self.frame.origin for a SKScene is bottom left.

Answer (score -1):

this is bottom left ---> `CGPoint topLeft = theView.frame.origin;`

top left is:

`CGPoint topLeft = theView.frame.origin+theView.frame.height;`